# python scrapy parse() function, where is the return value returned to?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new on Scrapy, and I am sorry if this question is trivial. I have read the document on Scrapy from official webpage. And while I look through the document, I met this example:

```
import scrapy
from myproject.items import MyItem

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = ’example.com’
  allowed_domains = [’example.com’]
  start_urls = [
  ’http://www.example.com/1.html’,
  ’http://www.example.com/2.html’,
  ’http://www.example.com/3.html’,
  ]

  def parse(self, response):
    for h3 in response.xpath(’//h3’).extract():
      yield MyItem(title=h3)
    for url in response.xpath(’//a/@href’).extract():
      yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

I know, the parse method must return an item or/and request, but where are these return values returned to?

One is an item and the other is request, I think these two type would be handled differently  and in the case of `CrawlSpider`, it has Rule with callback. What about this callback's return value? where to ? same as `parse()`?

I am very confused on Scrapy procedure, even i read the document....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#our-first-spider):

> The parse() method is in charge of processing the response and
>   returning scraped data (as Item objects) and more URLs to follow (as
>   Request objects).

In other words, returned/yielded items and requests are handled differently, items are being handed to the item pipelines and item exporters, but requests are being put into the `Scheduler` which pipes the requests to the `Downloader` for making a request and returning a response. Then, the engine receives the response and gives it to the spider for processing (to the `callback` method).

The whole data-flow process is described in the [Architecture Overview](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html) page in a very detailed manner.

Hope that helps.