# How to make Scrapy execute callbacks before the start_requests method finishes?

Tags: twisted, scrapy

I have a large file of relative urls that I want to scrape with Scrapy, and I've written some code to read this file line-by-line and build requests for my spider to parse. Below is some sample code.

spider:

```
def start_requests(self):
    with open(self._file) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            inlist = line.replace("\n","").split(",")
            item = MyItem(data = inlist[0])

            request = scrapy.Request(
                url = "http://foo.org/{0}".format(item["data"]),
                callback = self.parse_some_page
            )
            request.meta["item"]
            yield request


def parse_some_page(self,response):
    ...
    request = scrapy.Request(
        url = "http://foo.org/bar",
        callback = self.parse_some_page2
    )
    yield request
```

This works fine, but with a large input file, I'm seeing that `parse_some_page2` isn't invoked until `start_requests` finishes yielding all the initial requests. Is there some way I can make Scrapy start invoking the callbacks earlier? Ultimately, I don't want to wait for a million requests before I start seeing items flow through the pipeline.

Comment: I might be wrong but I think the scenario occurs because your yielding ``result`` in ``parse_some_page()``. What happens when you get rid of the yield?

Comment: @notorious.no I'm not sure what to do with the new request if I choose to omit the `yield`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came up with 2 solutions. 1) Run spiders in separate processes if there are too many large sites. 2) Use deferreds and callbacks via Twisted *(please don't run away, it won't be too scary)*. I'll discuss how to use the 2nd method because the first one can simply be googled.

Every function that executes `yield request` will "block" until a result is available. So your `parse_some_page()` function yields a scrapy response object and will not go on to the next URL until a response is returned. I did manage to find some sites (mostly foreign government sites) that take a while to fetch and hopefully it simulates a similar situation you're experiencing. Here is a quick and easy example:

```python
# spider/stackoverflow_spider.py

from twisted.internet import defer
import scrapy

class StackOverflow(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'stackoverflow'

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://www.gob.cl/en/',
            'http://www.thaigov.go.th/en.html',
            'https://www.yahoo.com',
            'https://www.stackoverflow.com',
            'https://swapi.co/',
        ]

        for index, url in enumerate(urls):
            # create callback chain after a response is returned
            deferred = defer.Deferred()
            deferred.addCallback(self.parse_some_page)
            deferred.addCallback(self.write_to_disk, url=url, filenumber=index+1)
            # add callbacks and errorbacks as needed

            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url,
                callback=deferred.callback)     # this func will start the callback chain AFTER a response is returned

    def parse_some_page(self, response):
        print('[1] Parsing %s' % (response.url))
        return response.body    # this will be passed to the next callback

    def write_to_disk(self, content, url, filenumber):
        print('[2] Writing %s content to disk' % (url))
        filename = '%d.html' % filenumber
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(content)
        # return what you want to pass to the next callback function
        # or raise an error and start Errbacks chain
```

I've changed things slightly to be a bit easier to read and run. The first thing to take note of in `start_requests()` is that [`Deferred`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html) objects are created and callback functions are being chained (via `addCallback()`) within the `urls` loop. Now take a look at the `callback` parameter for `scrapy.Request`:

```
yield scrapy.Request(
    url=url,
    callback=deferred.callback)
```

What this snippet will do is start the callback chain immediately after `scrapy.Response` becomes available from the request. In Twisted, `Deferreds` start running callback chains only after `Deferred.callback(result)` is executed with a value.

After a response is provided, the `parse_some_page()` function will run with the `Response` as an argument. What you will do is extract what ever you need here and pass it to the next callback (ie. `write_to_disk()` my example). You can add more callbacks to the `Deferred` in the loop if necessary.

So the difference between this answer and what you did originally is that you used `yield` to wait for all the responses first, then execute callbacks. Where as my method uses `Deferred.callback()` as the callback for each request such that each response will be processed immediately.

Hopefully this helps (and/or works).

### References

- [Twisted Deferred Reference](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer.html#callbacks)
- [Explanation of parse()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26196047/2172464): Briefly summarizes how yeild/return affects parsing.
- [Non-Blocking Recipes (Klien)](https://notoriousno.blogspot.com/2016/08/twisted-klein-non-blocking-recipes.html): I blog post I wrote a while back on async callbacks in Klien/Twisted. Might be helpful to newbies.

#### PS

I have no clue if this will actually work for you since I couldn't find a site that is too large to parse. Also, I'm brand-spankin' new at Scrapy :D but I have years of Twisted under my belt.

Comment: Thanks for such a nice response! I'm going to try it + read some things and get back to you.