# Python Scrapy Parse extracted link with another function

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scrapy i am trying to scrape yellowpages for learning purposes everything works fine but i want the email address, but to do that i need to visit links extracted inside parse and parse it with another parse_email function but it does not wok .

I mean i tested the parse_email function it works but it does not work from inside the main parse function, i want the parse_email function to get source of the link, so i am calling the parse_email function using the callback but it only returns links like these `<GET https://www.yellowpages.com/los-angeles-ca/mip/palm-tree-la-7254813?lid=7254813>` ***where it should return the email for some reason the parse_email function is not working and just returning the link without opening the page***

*here is the code i have commented the parts*

```
import scrapy
import requests
from urlparse import urljoin

scrapy.optional_features.remove('boto')

class YellowSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yellow spider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=restaurant&geo_location_terms=Los+Angeles%2C+CA']

    def parse(self, response):
        SET_SELECTOR = '.info'
        for brickset in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):

            NAME_SELECTOR = 'h3 a ::text'
            ADDRESS_SELECTOR = '.adr ::text'
            PHONE = '.phone.primary ::text'
            WEBSITE = '.links a ::attr(href)'


            #Getiing the link of the page that has the email usiing this selector
            EMAIL_SELECTOR = 'h3 a ::attr(href)'

            #extracting the link
            email = brickset.css(EMAIL_SELECTOR).extract_first()

            #joining and making complete url
            url = urljoin(response.url, brickset.css('h3 a ::attr(href)').extract_first())



            yield {
                'name': brickset.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                'address': brickset.css(ADDRESS_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                'phone': brickset.css(PHONE).extract_first(),
                'website': brickset.css(WEBSITE).extract_first(),

                #ONLY Returning Link of the page not calling the function

                'email': scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_email),
            }

        NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR = '.pagination ul a ::attr(href)'
        next_page = response.css(NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR).extract()[-1]
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                response.urljoin(next_page),
                callback=self.parse
            )

    def parse_email(self, response):

        #xpath for the email address in the nested page

        EMAIL_SELECTOR = '//a[@class="email-business"]/@href'

        #returning the extracted email WORKS XPATH WORKS I CHECKED BUT FUNCTION NOT CALLING FOR SOME REASON
        yield {
            'email': response.xpath(EMAIL_SELECTOR).extract_first().replace('mailto:', '')
        }
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong

Comment: would this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26196047/5699807) help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are yielding a `dict` with a `Request` inside of it, Scrapy won't dispatch it because it doesn't know it's there (they don't get dispatched automatically after creating them). You need to yield the actual `Request`.

In the `parse_email` function, in order to "remember" which item each email belongs to, you will need to pass the rest of the item data alongside the request. You can do this with the `meta` argument.

Example:

in `parse`:

```
yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_email, meta={'item': {
    'name': brickset.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
    'address': brickset.css(ADDRESS_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
    'phone': brickset.css(PHONE).extract_first(),
    'website': brickset.css(WEBSITE).extract_first(),
}})
```

in `parse_email`:

```
item = response.meta['item']  # The item this email belongs to
item['email'] = response.xpath(EMAIL_SELECTOR).extract_first().replace('mailto:', '')
return item
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'item'

Comment: Sorry, it was `response.meta['item']` as pointed out by @alecxe.

Comment: Thank you sir you are my new favorite person now you have no idea how long i was at it