# trying to send a Scrapy crawler to crawl a batch of links pulled from its first destination (recursive crawling). How to do it?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to make Scrapy follow some links I've already successfully scraped off a page.

There are two methods I've seen described, neither of which work for me.

### option 1

The first is from [the Scrapy tutorial](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html). Ctrl + F `yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)` to find the part I'm talking about. Here is me trying to emulate it:

```
import scrapy
import logging

logging.getLogger('scrapy').propagate = False

class SomeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "someSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["someplace.com/"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://someplace.com/AU/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response, y=False, x=False):
        if not x:
            links_to_follow = response.css('a::attr(href)').getall()
                for link in links_to_follow:
                    print(link)  # I've cut out some code, but this is always a URL, like www.google.ca
                    scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse(x=True))
        else:
            print("you are here")
```

The "you are here" statement is never reached. I get an error but it seems like this is an entirely bad approach: I'd rather have a separate parse function for the links I'm following because the pages I am parsing are different in character from the homepage.

#### option 2

Then there's this option that's basically, "write a specific parse function for the links you are crawling" from a StackOverflow thread titled ["Parse extracted link with another function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769246/python-scrapy-parse-extracted-link-with-another-function). It uses `response.follow_all()`.

What it looks like when I do it:

```
    def parse(self, response, y=False, x=False):

        links_to_follow = response.css('a::attr(href)').getall()
            for link in links_to_follow:
                print(link)  # I've cut out some code, but this is always a URL, like www.google.ca
        response.follow_all(links_to_follow, self.parse_products)


    def parse_products(self, response):
        print("you are here")
```

Doesn't get to "you are here".

### option 3

I found a [third supposed solution](https://utopiangeek.com/scrapy-pass-argument-to-callback-function/) while looking for how to pass an argument to a callback function. My attempt:

```
    def parse(self, response, y=False, x=False):
        links_to_follow = response.css('a::attr(href)').getall()
           for link in links_to_follow:
                print(link)  # I've cut out some code, but this is always a URL, like www.google.ca
                scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_products, meta={"x":True})

    def parse_products(self, response):
        print("you are here")
```

Doesn't get to "you are here".

If I can get to the "you are here" line with the `response` param coming thru with the data from the page like it does in the starting `parse` method, I'll be able to take it from there. I just don't get that line printing like I expect it to.

A footnote: I've cut out a lot of code without testing whether the abridged versions would run. But I guarantee that in all of my code, the variable I'm plugging in to `scrapy.Request` or `response.follow_all` contains a link or a list of links when I run it. The line I expect to start crawling the link is reached but the `parse` or `parse_products` bit doesn't execute.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this by using meta from the start itself

```py
def parse(self, response):
    x = response.meta.get('x', False)
    y = response.meta.get('y', False)
    if not x:
        links_to_follow = response.css('a::attr(href)').getall()
        for link in links_to_follow:
            print link  # I've cut out some code, but this is always a URL, like www.google.ca
            yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse, meta={'x': True})
    else:
        print 'you are here'
```

Also make sure to remove `allowed_domains` from your crawler, since this is a open crawler where domain names are not known from the start

Comment: When I do this, I still don't get ```parse``` running again for each of the links in the ```links_to_follow```. That's what I'm after: Scrapy requesting the links in the ```links_to_follow```, visiting them, and then interacting with their html.

Comment: You were missing a `yield` as well before the `scrapy.Request`

Comment: Putting a ```yield``` doesn't cause the "you are here" to run though. I checked in both ```parse_products``` scenarios

Comment: Also make sure you are not using any `allowed_domains` which will filter the request outside the starting domain you may have. Another recommendation for initial testing will be to use `dont_filter=True` as well for the requests you yield

Answer (score 0):

What I was missing, in the end, was...

(1) When I ran `scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_products)` in my tests, my `parse_products` method was missing a crucial line. See the commented line here:

```
    def parse_products(self, response):
        print("you are here")
        divs = response.css("div.product-tile > div::attr(class)").getall()
        yield divs  # "yield divs" was necessary to make the code output what I wanted.
```

(2) I had to put the `dont_filter` flag as `True`, as Tarun Lalwani said in his post.

I don't understand exactly why Scrapy is so keen on `yield` however. Is it something to do with how programs handle huge data? I saw that mentioned while researching `yield`.